# Rotation has no effect on GetPath?

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi (XE5) to create a graphic component. One challenge is to rotate a closed path by SetWorldTransform, then read back the outline with GetPath. Rotation works ok, but the points retreived from GetPath are not rotated (however, obtating a region (PathToRegion) works as expected!).

My code:

```
procedure Rotate(DestBitmap : TBitmapEx; Radians : Single;  FigureRect : TRect);

// DestBitmap is where to draw the figure. Size of DestBitmap is computed from
//the actual angle and figure size (not shown here). FigureRect is the plain
//figure rectangle without rotation

var
  XForm: tagXFORM;
  C, S : single;
  Points : array of TPoint;
  NumPoints : integer;
  Bytes : TByteArray;
  Rgn : HRGN;
  X, Y : integer;

 begin
  //Locate FigureRect to center of bitmap: 
  X := (DestBitmap.Width - FigureRect.Width) div 2;
  Y := (DestBitmap.Height - FigureRect.Height) div 2;
  FigureRect.Location := Point(X,Y);

  //Set rotate mode 
  C := Cos(Radians);
  S := Sin(Radians);
  XForm.eM11 := C;
  XForm.eM12 := S;
  XForm.eM21 := -S;
  XForm.eM22 := C;
  XForm.eDx := (DestBitmap.Width - DestBitmap.Width * C +
    DestBitmap.Height * S) / 2;
  XForm.eDy := (DestBitmap.Height - DestBitmap.Width * S -
    DestBitmap.Height * C) / 2;
  SetGraphicsMode(DestBitmap.Canvas.Handle, GM_ADVANCED);
  SetWorldTransform(DestBitmap.Canvas.Handle, XForm);

  //Rotate the figure
  BeginPath(DestBitmap.Canvas.Handle);
  DestBitmap.Canvas.Rectangle(FigureRect);
  EndPath(DestBitmap.Canvas.Handle);
  FlattenPath(DestBitmap.Canvas.Handle);
  NumPoints := GetPath(DestBitmap.Canvas.Handle, Points[0], Bytes[0], 0);
  SetLength(Points, NumPoints);
  GetPath(DestBitmap.Canvas.Handle, Points[0], Bytes[0], NumPoints);

  //Points now describes the plain, unrotated figure, but if instead:
  //Rgn := PathToRegion(DestBitmap.Canvas.Handle);
  //Rgn describes the rotated area, as expected 
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is expected, `GetPath` returns points in logical coordinates. Whereas the resulting region of `PathToRegion` uses device coordinates - so it is unaffected by the transform. See documentation of both functions.

Or three, `SetWorldTransform` transforms logical coordinates. To everything in the logical world, nothing has been changed. The transform is with respect to the device.